# snapshotChanges() does not work in Angular dialog

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use file-upload.component.ts that works fine when using in another component as child component, but when using in dialog (as a child), it doesn't work as expected.

```
startUpload(event: FileList) {

    const file = event.item(0);
    const ref = this.storage.ref(this.imagePath);
    this.task = this.storage.upload(this.imagePath, file);

    // snapshotChanges() doesn't complete in Angular material dialog.
    this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe( 
      finalize(async () => {
        this.downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
      })
    );

}
```

The file gets uploaded to Firebase Storage, but snapshotChanges() does not run, and I don't get any downloadURL.